# Start Ubuntu Unity With Dash Open

Tags: unity, unity-dash

How do you start ubuntu unity 3D with the dash open? This is so that I can get things done fast. I would like to log in to my desktop with a full-screen dash without having to click the Ubuntu dash button.

Comment: Related: [Opening Unity 2D Dash](https://answers.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+question/145126)

Comment: This is Unity 3D. Very Different.

Comment: Unity 2D is designed to replicate the functionality of Unity 3D. From an investigative point of view, information on how to perform the desired action in Unity 2D could turn out to be indispensable in discovering its Unity 3D analogue. I maintain that the link is related, and suggest that it is *highly* so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One (somewhat hackish) solution could be to simulate a [<kbd>Super</kbd>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45019/what-should-i-call-this-key) keystroke every time you log in.

You can do this by adding the following [xdotool](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xdotool) [image: Install xdotool] command to your Startup Applications:

```
xdotool key Super_L
```

Comment: I'm getting this message: "The image you are requesting does not exist or is no longer available" next to the link to xdotool.

Comment: search it up in ubuntu software center

Comment: @Flimm It's supposed to be an Ubuntu Software Center icon. I generated the link using [this script](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/548/how-to-post-links-that-install-software-via-apt/549#549), and the image loads correctly for me. I'm not sure what might be going wrong.

Comment: it is an Ubuntu Software Center icon

Comment: @Flimm [Discussion of the problem](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1852/software-centre-image-link-is-broken)