# Where is the accessories folder located?

Tags: 11.10, notify-osd

I installed NotifyOSD Config but I can't find the accessories folder in Ubuntu 11.10 where `notifyosd` should be located.

Does anyone know where it is or how to open it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The design of Unity trades ease of accessing any arbitrary application for [ease of accessing a small number of "preferred applications"](http://unity.ubuntu.com/projects/unity/). This means that browsing to anything but the most commonly used applications now requires a little more work.

To get a list of Accessories, you now must click **Ubuntu button ▸ More Apps ▸ Filter results ▸ Accessories ▸ Installed: See more results**.

[image: Accessories]

In the case that you know what you're looking for ahead of time, though, it is immensely faster to use Unity's search function. Press [<kbd>Super</kbd>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45019/what-should-i-call-this-key) to open the dash, then just start typing what you want. <kbd>Enter</kbd> will launch the topmost result.

Comment: Great screenshot would have never found it Thanks for your reply.

Comment: To the user who cast an anonymous downvote: Please explain your concerns about this answer so that it can be improved. Doing otherwise is cowardly and is detrimental to this community.